# Using text box info as variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm making a rock,paper,scissors game using Javascript and I'm having some trouble starting. I need to have a text box and submit button, then the user input of "rock", "paper", "scissors" will be played against the computer's random choice. How would I have the computer take what's entered into the text field and run it against the computers choice? I'm a novice and in need of a nudge in the right direction, because I'm not sure how to start this problem.

Thanks

Edit:
So, a friend sent me some code and I added onto some of it and it looks like it would work(at least to me), but I'm not sure what to set the variable "player" equal to in order to equal the textbox information.

```
var player = 


var choices = ["rock","paper","scissors"];
var computer = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];

var win = "Your "+player+" beats "+computer+". You win.";
var lose = "Your "+player+" loses to "+computer+". You lose.";
var draw = "A draw: "+player+" on "+computer+".";

if(player === "rock"){
    if(computer === "scissors"){
        result = win;
        alert="win";
    }
    else if(computer === "paper"){
        result = lose;
        alert="lose";
    }
    else if(computer === "rock"){
        result = draw;
        alert="draw";
    }
}
else if(player === "paper"){
    if(computer === "rock"){
        result = win;
        alert="win";
    }
    else if(computer === "scissors"){
      result = lose;
        alert="lose";
    }
    else if(computer === "paper"){
        result = draw;
        alert="draw";
    }
}
else if(player === "scissors"){
    if(computer === "paper"){
        result = win;
        alert="win";
    }
    else if(computer === "rock"){
        result = lose;
        alert="lose";
    }
    else if(computer === "scissors"){
        result = draw;
        alert="draw";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="rockTextInput" size="100" placeholder="Rock, Paper, or Scissors" >
<input type="button" id="Button" value="Play Hand">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you even google anything?

Answer (score 0):

The computer's choice could be generated like this:

```
...
var plays = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

alert("Computer played: " + plays[rand]);

//Check to see the winner
...
```

Hope that helps give you a start.

Comment: `var plays = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};` gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`, maybe you meant to write an _Array_ literal instead? .. e.g. `['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']` (square brackets, not braces)

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks. I've been doing too much ``C`` lately and got a bit mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limited number of possibilities, a way to do it is with a look-up table. You'd have to use further JavaScript to link it to your HTML. For that you'll probably want to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) with an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input)'s [*value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties) and output to some other [*Element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element).

```
/*
Usage:
play(player_choice)
    player_choice String, 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'
returns Object with properties
    player String, player's choice
    ai String, ai's choice
    result Integer, 0 - lose, 1 - draw, 2 - win
    resultText String, description of result
*/
var play = (function () {
    var options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
        result_table = {
            'rock': {
                'rock': 1,
                'paper': 0,
                'scissors': 2
            },
            'paper': {
                'rock': 2,
                'paper': 1,
                'scissors': 0
            },
            'scissors': {
                'rock': 0,
                'paper': 2,
                'scissors': 1
            }
        },
        result_text = ['AI wins', 'Draw', 'Player wins'];
    return function (player_choice) {
            var ai_choice;
            player_choice = player_choice.toLowerCase();
            if (!result_table.hasOwnProperty(player_choice)) {
                throw '[' + player_choice + '] not a valid choice.';
            }
            ai_choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
            return {
                    'player': player_choice,
                    'ai': ai_choice,
                    'result': result_table[player_choice][ai_choice],
                    'resultText': result_text[result_table[player_choice][ai_choice]]
                };
        };
}());
```